# Point distance in pylab plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if there was a way to "measure" a distance in a plot made with pylab. I can remember something useful in gnuplot, where one could move his mouse cursor on a point in order to gain its coordinates.

Comment: Most backends provide this functionality, where you can hover the plot and read the data coordinates somewhere in the plot window. See e.g. [this](http://www.robertocolistete.net/MatPlotLib/histogram_N9_Qt4backend.png) example.

Comment: It's also fairly easy to implement something like this yourself, see e.g. [event handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html), and extend that to measuring a distance (e.g. click twice, print `dx`, `dy`)